# how to return an object in a suspended function after receiving the object from a Flow?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I'm wondering if there's a way to wait for a flow to be complete and return the result inside a suspend function. `transactionRepository.getAll(accountId)` returns a flow of transactions

```
override suspend fun getAccount(accountId: Int): Account {
    val account = Account(accountRepository.get(accountId))
    transactionRepository.getAll(accountId).mapIterable {
        val transaction = Transaction(it)
        val category = Category(categoryRepository.get(it.categoryId))
        transaction.category = category
        transaction.account = account
        return@mapIterable transaction
    }.collect {
        account.transactions = it
     }

    //TODO: How can i return an account after the flow has been executed?
}
```

getAll function defined in my repository:

```
fun getAll(accountId: Int): Flow<List<DatabaseTransaction>>
```

Comment: I assume `account.transactions` is expecting a list of transactions?

Comment: yeah that's correct

Comment: What type is returned by `getAll`, and where is the function `mapIterable` from?

Comment: getAll returns a Flow<List<DatabaseTansaction>> and mapIterable is an extension function that basically does a map twice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want just the first value returned by the flow, and it's a `List<Transaction>`, you can use `first()`. But I'm only guessing because I don't know what `getAll()` returns and I'm not familiar with `mapIterable`.

```
override suspend fun getAccount(accountId: Int): Account {
    val account = Account(accountRepository.get(accountId))
    val transactionsFlow: Flow<List<Transaction>> = transactionRepository.getAll(accountId).mapIterable {
        val transaction = Transaction(it)
        val category = Category(categoryRepository.get(it.categoryId))
        transaction.category = category
        transaction.account = account
        return@mapIterable transaction
    }
    account.transactions = transactionsFlow.first()
    return account
}
```

Comment: This looks like its gonna solve my problem, will mark as resolved when verified

Answer (score 0):

You could do two things

First one would be to use the `.toList()` on the flow which I think gives you the list you want then you can just do a normal for loop on that list to set the data

```
val transactions = transactionRepository.getAll(accountId).toList()

transactions.forEach{
    val transaction = Transaction(it)
    val category = Category(categoryRepository.get(it.categoryId))
    transaction.category = category
    transaction.account = account
}

account.transactions = transactions
```

Second would be to just return the account after the collect like you normally would.

```
val account = Account(accountRepository.get(accountId))
transactionRepository.getAll(accountId).mapIterable {
    val transaction = Transaction(it)
    val category = Category(categoryRepository.get(it.categoryId))
    transaction.category = category
    transaction.account = account
    return@mapIterable transaction
}.collect {
    account.transactions = it
 }

return account
```

See this example I made

https://pl.kotl.in/wWmLiqBtz

Comment: If the source flow is one that never completes, like one from a database that monitors the database indefinitely for changes, then `toList()` and `collect()` will never return.

Comment: @Tenfour04 that is a good caveat for these cases

Comment: @Tenfour04 have collects on flows from the database in other places in my code and they seem to be working great though

Comment: but ur definitly right about toList() not returning anything

Comment: `collect` does serve a purpose. When I say it doesn’t return, I mean the code under it is never reached. The lambda passed to `collect` will run for each item that is emitted, but the function call itself will suspend forever.